# Makefile for g++ defaults to /usr/bin/g++

Tags: makefile, g++

I'm working with a makefile where g++ defaults to using /usr/bin/g++. How do I set it to a an executable in a different path?

Comment: Are you using the Make variable `CXX`?

Answer (score 0):

Same as you would in a shell script: Prepend the path to the PATH environment variable:

```
PATH := /other/path:$(PATH)

printpath:
    env | grep PATH
```

Or in the calling environment:

```
PATH=/other/path:$PATH make ...
# or
export PATH...
make ...
```

Alternatively you overload the variable for g++ in the recipe (CXX) with the full path:

```
CXX := /other/path/g++
```